# Instrumenting Jersey2.x Resources with Dropwizard

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, dropwizard, instrumentation

I am developing a sample application using dropwizard and jersey2.x.In that application  want to instrument jersey resources.I don't know how to apply instrumentation to jersey api.I have read the documentation and there is no help regarding configuration it.
Here is the link of the docs
https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics/3.1.0/manual/jersey/ 
Please help .